# White margin error on site when viewing on landscape ipad bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, viewport

Built a site using bootstrap 3, looks great and works great on all devices apart from an iPad 4 landscape. Im currently able to slide to the left on the site and a white margin appears offsite. My container width is 1044px, and content width 1024px (container width - 2x10px gutters).

Any ideas or help appreciated

Comment: Where can we see the white margin? :)

Comment: please consider adding some code or url where we can see the actual problem. unless you will not put code or url its really hard to give solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your container width should be 1024px, as iPad 4 landscape resolution is 1024 x 768 px

```
.container{
  width:1024px;
}
```

Comment: Should'nt the site resize to fit the viewport?

Comment: @user2039247: what do you mean by resize to fit the viewport? if you mean container width should fit to the viewport width, then that is what I suggested in my answer.